# Can we please remove the 200 character minimum on the careers personal statement?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

Minimum lengths do NOT produce good content. They produce filler. This is not exactly a new thought, and my existing personal statement (now short by ~70 characters) is, I think, a nice example of brevity.

Also, when did the minimum get added? Because I missed that, and since it has 'put my matches on hold', I'd kind of like to have known when it happened. I only noticed because I was updating my current job description anyway.

Comment: Agreed. Character minimums in questions are fine, but how much we write in our careers statements is none of anybody's business.

Comment: Personal statements are rubbish anyhow.  "Please blow hard for 200 characters." Boring and worthless.

Comment: I inhabit a parallel universe where candidates apply for academic positions in a structured system allowing one and only one (standard letter sized) page of a personal statement. It's amazing how much information you can get from that. If next year, suddenly 100 pages were allowed, I would never be able to read them, and as you say, 99 would consistently be filler. A minimum is useful, but 200 characters is not enough.

Comment: From their end though they may have the limit there for a reason.  Simply displaying it in an export or somewhere on your profile may look better using the min 200 characters

Comment: I bet 201 doesn't look any worse

Comment: @JonH then that's a UI design issue, not something you pass down to the consumer.

Comment: The ability to write a concise career description could suggest the ability to write concise code. Some employers appreciate that.

Comment: There should be a limit, because nobody is interested in reading a dissertation when they are expecting a concise, honest personal statement, but I think 200 characters is a bit short.

Comment: @whirlwin - 200 is presently a LOWER limit, not an UPPER limit. My objection is that my existing statement is only about 140 characters, and I object to padding it out. Yes, there needs to be some upper limit (I don't know what), but in this one I'm objecting to a minimum not a maximum.

Comment: Is adding 70 spaces at the end a solution?

Comment: So many people reading "minimum" as "maximum". (So did I at first.) Great example of how the brain does semantics.

Comment: This is a classic example of "we want data X to exist, so we will force it to exist". The results of that approach are usually terrible. The much better approach is to motivate the data creators with feedback, incentives, fun, reminders etc.

Comment: @josilber - the point is, an end user shouldn't HAVE to do that, and that's kinda the point that's being driven here.  Forcing the end users to use workarounds to exceed an arbitrary minimum character limit is putting a burden on the end user, and might not look so great if the data is actually exported to some other format.

Comment: @user2366842 I hear you and generally agree that the character minimum doesn't make sense; I was just wondering if that was a workaround.

Comment: @josilber `rtrim('Is adding 70 spaces at the end a solution?                                                                      ')`

Comment: @Dribbler: I think you're confusing a *minimum* with a *maximum*. Your one-page thing is a *maximum*. Michael's issue is with a 200-character *minimum*.

Comment: Oh my goodness, @TJCrowder you're right. What a great question, then. If someone came in with a 10 character personal statement that really stood out (in a good way), that would be a great way to stand out :)

Answer (score 25):

The 200 character minimum was introduced in a new onboarding process for new users creating CVs. If someone indicates that they want to be contacted by employers, we need to have enough information about them that employers can actually decide if the person matches the skills they're looking for. So we introduced several required fields, and the personal statement is one of them. We did that because the personal statement is the most flexible of all sections on the CV, and it's the best place for developers to be explicit about who they are, what kind of job they're looking for, how they philosophically approach software development, etc.

We're currently planning on revising those minimum requirements based on several weeks of actual data from new users creating CVs, and we are planning to reduce or eliminate the 200 character requirement on the personal statement. There will still be requirements that you must meet in order to appear in an employer's search results and be eligible to receive messages, but the personal statement piece will likely be changing.

Answer (score 22):

The 200 character minimum can be bypassed with an HTML comment:

```
<!-- Here is a 200+ character comment 
......................................
......................................
......................................
......................................
......... -->
```

Comment: There's always a workaround.